# C++ | No instance of constructor matches the argument list

Tags: c++, arrays, class, char

I really do not understand this error.

My class:

```
class Child : public Parent {

private:
    char dllName[250];
    char processName[250];

public:
    Child(char dllNameL, char processNameL) {
        char dllName[] = { dllNameL };
        char processName[] = { processNameL };
    }
}
```

My usage:

```
char colDllName[250] = {};
char colProcessName[250] = {};

cout << "Enter DLL name: ";
cin >> colDllName;
cout << "Enter process name: ";
cin >> colProcessName;

Child info(colDllName, colProcessName);
```

**Problem**

On the last line in `my usage`, the `colDllName` (first argument in the object) is erroring out. what is wrong?

Comment: Well, a `char[250]` isn't the same as a `char`.

Comment: Use `std::string` and some of your pain will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

1. `dllName` and `processName` stay uninitialized after constructor. (You instantiate two local char-arrays and initialize each one with a string that contains exactly **one** char instead. When you leave the constructor, those two local arrays go out of scope, and your `Child` object remains largely uninitialized.) Use something like `strcpy` if you want to intialize them with the contents of char-array constructor arguments.
2. But `Child::Child` is declared to not accept two char-arrays but rather two chars. This is why exactly that line in your program does not compile.
3. Have you considered using `std::string`s instead?..